# Need to create a calendar with drag and drop events. Which control to use?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, calendar, tablelayoutpanel

I'm using VB.Net 2012 Express

I need to create a calendar which will have drag and drop elements. I'll be linking it to a database but first I need to work out which control to use to create the calendar display.

I want to be able to create events by dragging a rectangle with the mouse.  Also to move the event by dragging and dropping the event.

I'm trying to use a tablelayoutpanel (tlp).  I can create the tlp programmatically, but can't see how to tell which row or column the mouse is in when I click, as it only gives me the X and Y but not the tablelayoutpanel row or column.

How can I find out which row/column I was in on mouse down, and which row/column on mouse up? Or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Comment: `GDI+` with mouse events

Comment: I can see how to get X and Y with mouse events, but not the row or column?

Comment: Each day would be a `Rectangle` and you can check mouse clicks with `Rectangle.Contains(e.x, e.y)`, you would be in-charge of placing them in rows/columns - for loop with condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks OneFineDay, you set me on the right path.  I veered off a bit, but came up with this and it works:

```
 Private Sub Layout_Calendar_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Layout_Calendar.MouseDown
    Dim x As Integer
    x = e.X

    Dim y As Integer
    y = e.Y

    Dim Allcolumns() As Integer
    Dim ColumnLocation As Integer
    Dim Column As Integer

    Dim Allrows() As Integer
    Dim RowLocation As Integer
    Dim Row As Integer


    'find column
    Allcolumns = Layout_Calendar.GetColumnWidths()
    ColumnLocation = 0
    Column = 0
    For Each Colwidth In Allcolumns
        ColumnLocation += Colwidth
        If x < ColumnLocation Then
            Exit For
        Else
            Column += 1
        End If
    Next


    Allrows = Layout_Calendar.GetRowHeights()
    RowLocation = 0
    Row = 0
    For Each Rowwidth In Allrows
        RowLocation += Rowwidth
        If y < RowLocation Then
            Exit For
        Else
            Row += 1
        End If
    Next

    Console.WriteLine("Column:" & Column & " Row:" & Row)

End Sub
```